# Printing CSS and Page Breaks

Tags: css, printing

I want to insert a page break when users print my web page.

IE 7, Mozilla 3.0 , any Chrome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the CSS [page-break-before](http://w3schools.com/Css/pr_print_pagebb.asp) or [page-break-after](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_print_pageba.asp) properties in a print media style sheet to achieve this.

For example:

```
<style>
    @media print {
        table {
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: @user326096 - What tag are you using it on? (Try a DIV - it should work fine in Chrome.)

Comment: Works fine for me in IE, doesn't work in Chrome. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I have only had to do this once, but this worked just fine in IE7/IE8. Not sure about Chrome or Firefox though.

```
<div>This is before the page break.</div>
<div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
<div>This is after the page break.</div>
```

Comment: Actually, it does work in Chrome v8.0.552.224. Do you have any floating divs, by chance? If so, it might just be a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Although most Internet users prefer to read web pages online, some of your users might want to print the article text and then read it.

With CSS, you can control the location of broken pages and go to the next page when printing. Just add the following CSS code to your styles, and then assign the page-break class to each tag you want to print on the next page.

```
page-break {
  page-break-before: always;
}
```